# jQuery AJAX POST Form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, post

I tried to parse the form value into data variable for body request, but the body always return empty. It's mean my script not working to print the field value type by user into body data.
within the HTML form:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="MSISDN" name="MSISDN" placeholder="MSISDN"/>
    <input type="text" id="channel" name="channel" placeholder="channel"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here my javascript

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://apiurl.com/users',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'post',
    headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF8',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'api-key': 'judmkd895849438'
  },
    contentType: 'application/json',


    data: JSON.stringify( { "MSISDN": $('#MSISDN').val(), "channel": $('0').val() } ),
    //data: JSON.stringify( {MSISDN: document.getElementById("MSISDN").value, channel: "0"} ),


    processData: false,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
</script>
<div id="response">
    <pre></pre>
</div>
```

If the request success the response is:

```
{
    "UserDetails": [
        {
            "status": "Enabled",
            "UserID": "ABCS884784",
            "UserNo": "897363762827"
        }
    ],
    "customerStatus": null,
    "responseCode": 0,
    "responseMessage": "Details Fetched Successfully "
}
```

but within my code the response always return error

```
"{\"customerStatus\":null,\"responseCode\":-2,\"responseMessage\":\"Inputs are invalid.\"}"
```

that's mean the body value not filling up, can not fond whats wrong with my code so far

Any help will appreciate,

Comment: Please clarify what is this `$('0').val()`?

Comment: That's the default value for channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `dataType: 'text'` as jQuery is intelligent to guess what (xml, json, script, or html) to expect in the response. Also remove `processData: false` as you are not sending DOMDocument, or other non-processed data.

```
$('#my-form').submit(function () {
    var formData = {
         MSISDN : $('#MSISDN').val(),
         channel : $('#channel').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apiurl.com/users',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF8',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'api-key': 'judmkd895849438'
      },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            console.log(data);
            $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response, but still nothing print on the console or #response, if I remove the function at the top of code, is printed but said error null value

Comment: Probably the endpoint just needs plain javascript object. Could you replace `data: { MSISDN : 'Test', channel : 'Test' }`

Comment: Hi @Hasta Tamang, replaced the data but still no response print.

Comment: Still getting inputs are invalid?

Comment: The response did not show any errors but won't print the result response :(

Comment: If your ajax request is a success but do not get any response back, you might have to investigate at the endpoint or the form parameters carefully. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the ajax immediately after load but you need to call it on submit try this.

```
  $('#my-form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apiurl.com/users',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF8',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'api-key': 'judmkd895849438'
      },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { "MSISDN": $('#MSISDN').val(), "channel": $('#channel').val() },
        success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi @Josef Katič thanks for the suggestions, but the #response pre did not print nothing, how to print it and display on the html page?

Comment: @Bireon Try to put the script on the end of file. Also try to `console.log(data);`

Comment: Still not showing anything on console log, and i expect to print it on a html page also

Comment: @Bireon I have removed `JSON.stringify()` try it now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still not working, i also tried several with no luck :(